# Difference between TextChanged property and AutoPostBack property with respect to ASP.NET TextBox control

Tags: asp.net

I am reading the textbook "Sams ASP.NET 4 unleashed" and I am confused about the Difference between TextChanged property and AutoPostBack property with respect to ASP.NET TextBox control.

The book explains the two properties as :

> AutoPostBack—Enables you to post the form containing the TextBox back
>   to the  server automatically when the contents of the TextBox is
>   changed.

then,

> TextChanged—Raised on the server when the contents of the text box are
>   changed.

Then it continues to explain :

> When the AutoPostBack property has the value True, the form containing
>   the TextBox is  automatically posted back to the server when the
>   contents of the TextBox changes. If you modify the contents of the
>   text box and tab out of the TextBox control, the form is automatically
>   posted back to the server, and the contents of the TextBox display.

The line that confused me is this one :

> You can handle TextChanged event even when you don’t use the
>   AutoPostBack property.

Well, what is the difference between Autopostback property and textchanged property of both cause the page to be posted again to the server? Or is it that the working of both the methods differ from each other? I am confused..please help me understand it better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You can handle TextChanged event even when you don’t use the AutoPostBack property.

Yes, that's true. You can handle the `TextChanged`  event on the next roundtrip to the server even if it doesn't post back immediately.

- So when you handle the event and `AutoPostBack` is set to `true`, the postback will happen immediately and the TextChanged-event is raised.
- When `AutoPostBack` is set to `false`, you can handle the event anyway on the next postback(f.e. a button-click)

> what is the difference between Autopostback property and textchanged property of **both cause the page to be posted again to the server**?

So the bold printed is simply wrong. 
The difference is that the one controls the postback-behaviour and the other registers an event handler.

Answer (score 2):

TextChanged will be raised when postback is completed and directed to self page. After Load cycle this event is raised. Which means that TextChanged is raising between two postbacks.

AutoPostBack property is activating postback, when content of textbox is changed and focused out from this textbox. After that postback occurs, page is directed to self. Then again after Load cycle TextChanged event is raised.

Also TextChanged is an 'event' not property.